# Docker Django 404 for web static files, but fine for admin static files

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

please help me on this docker django configuration for serving static files.

my `Django` project running on `Docker` got some issues with delivering `static files`.

> All static files for **admin view** is loading fine, but static files for client web view is throwing 404 Not found Error.

This is my **`docker.yml`** configuration details:

```
web:
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
  volumes:
    - ./web:/usr/src/app
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  env_file: .env
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

postgres:
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

#### update

This is the admin static file url will look like :
*http://developer.com:8000/static/admin/css/base.css*
and this is how client static file url looks like:
*http://developer.com:8000/static/css/base.css*
Where those admin folder in static directory is creator by running django command `collectstatic`

I have used this setting previously, and was working fine. But when I moved the project root folder to another directory seems have this issue.

I am totally stuck here, many many thanks for all your help and feedback.

Comment: What is yout static root and staticfile_dirs in settings.py?

Comment: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
`STATIC_ROOT      =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`

Only these two configurations are there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This was issue with the **`STATICFILES_DIRS`** configuration in the **`settings.py`** file.

> This setting defines the additional locations the **staticfiles** app will traverse if the **FileSystemFinder** finder is enabled, e.g. if you use the collectstatic or findstatic management command or use the static file serving view.

Following was the configuration in my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT      =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

Now I updated this code to:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

And every files is loading fine.

Reference [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs)

Comment: This worked, thanks! Its strange why it would fail in the container. Just a NOTE: depending on the path you are using for static files you may need to add / at the end of static.

Comment: I’ve just encountred this. So did you remove STATIC__ROOT? Do you have a github example app handy please?

Comment: @GlennSampson Yes I have removed the `STATIC_ROOT` fromt he `settings.py`

Comment: If I remove `STATIC_ROOT`, I get an error: `You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.`

Answer (score 13):

Use [Whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html) to make your life easier when dealing with static files in django.

1.If you are using docker-compose,add whitenoise to your requirements.txt file:

```
whitenoise==3.3.1
```

2.Add whitenoise to your middleware apps inside **settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [# 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware','whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',# ...]
```

make sure that you add this below your **security.SecurityMiddleware** app

3.Finally, change the following variables inside settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'<app_name>/static'),os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

Be sure to replace  with the name of your app. Note that this only applies if your static files are stored in(for example) **my_project/app/static/app/**.

Otherwise if your static folder is located in **my_project/app/static**:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

4. Lastly disable the built-in django static file server as follows:

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
   # ...
   'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   # ...]
   ```

Comment: Tried this but still I get 404, do I need to execute collectstatic as well?

Comment: This is a great answer, and has solved my number one frustration with Django

Comment: You saved me hours of time with a Docker integration, thank you so much!

Comment: I wasted 2 hours and was pretty sure static file stuff was completely broken in Docker. Tried this out of desperation and it worked immediately. Godsend.

Answer (score 0):

As you have moved your project to another directory, there is a possibility that the path of your static directories are also different now. `Django in most scenarios use apache, nginx or some other web servers to serve static files`. One point to notice is that your static directory should be accessed publicly. I had gone through a problem like this before. What I did was I `moved static dir to document root mentioned in apache config file`.

So move your static files to the doc root of apache and update static directories in settings.py to refer to the static directory in your apache doc root. I hope this helps.

Comment: I have moved all my `static` folder to DocumentRoot Path, but not worked.

Comment: can you access your doc root in browser using url <server-ip> or <hostname>? Try accessing a css file or any static file. url would be like `http://your-ip/static/css/bootstrap.css`.