# Getting 404 error messages after placing Django Python app in Docker Container

Tags: python, django, docker, http-status-code-404

I am trying to get some template information to display on a web page served in from a  `Docker container`. It is using `uWSGI`. The name of the template is `base.html`

There are "decorations" associated with the `base.html` file that are located in the `static directory`. To be more specific, it resides in the `static/wforms/assets` directory.
Below is how the `assets` directory is being used in the template.

```
<link href="{% static 'wforms/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{% static 'wforms/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{% static 'wforms/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Whenever I go to a page that uses the `base.html` template, the decorations are not found and the resulting web page is a mess. Everything works fine in PyCharm. The problem happens when moving everything to the directory structure in a Docker Container. Below is the directory structure in PyCharm.

[image]

I start the container like this:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888  -v /home/dockcclubdjango/apps/wforms/assets:/code/backendworkproj/static/wforms/assets --name my-running-app my-python-app
```

As an FYI, the **/home/dockcclubdjango/apps/wforms/assets** does exist and has the correct info in it.

Then, I attempt to go to the web home page. The page shows up but all of the "decorations" are not present. So, the page looks somewhat messy. Like this:

[image]

I look at the source code of the page and see the following below.

```
<link href="/static/wforms/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  <<< got 404 error in log file
    <link href="/static/wforms/assets/global/plugins/morris/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />                                  <<< got 404 error in log file
    <link href="/static/wforms/assets/global/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />                  <<< got 404 error in log file
```

I noticed that any item associated with the `assets` directory cannot be found. **Each of the items listed gets a `404 Error` in the log.**

So, I tried the following to start the `Docker Container` differently (as seen below) but it did not work

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888  -v /home/dockcclubdjango/apps/wforms/assets:/static/wforms/assets --name my-running-app my-python-app
```

I started looking at the `settings.py` file but am not sure of what could be wrong.

**settings.py file (reduced to make it more simple - focusing on STATIC dirs**

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

DEBUG = True

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backendworkproj.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backendworkproj.wsgi.application'

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 10*60


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/cclub.com/static/"

MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
```

I saw this thread
[Docker Django 404 for web static files, but fine for admin static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627393/docker-django-404-for-web-static-files-but-fine-for-admin-static-files)

and made the changes suggested in it but things still did not work (the "decorations" on the page kept showing up with 404 errors. Not sure of where to look next. What am I missing here?

TIA

## Update

@PekosoG - When I used the suggestion below, I get the following when running **docker build -t my-python-app .**

```
 ---> Running in fde638af597f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/backendworkproj/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 199, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
    for finder in get_finders():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 264, in get_finders
    yield get_finder(finder_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 277, in get_finder
    return Finder()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 66, in __init__
    "The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting
```

## Update

Reverted back to old setup (since he solution above did not solve the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, never mind. I found that this is what solved the problem for me. Not sure if its the best option - but - it works ...

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/StaticFiles.html

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and i solve it like this:

**Settings File**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_FOLDER = 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,STATIC_FOLDER),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

and also when i run the manage.py commands to initialize i added this

```
python manage.py collectstatic -link --noinput
```

Comment: thanks for the response! Am I reading it correctly that STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT both use "statics" and not "static"? TIA

Comment: yes, i forgot to mention that in my moment of panic i changed my "static" route to "statics", let me edit that from my answer