# Django - JavaScript from static files not loading, but other resources are

Tags: javascript, python, django, docker

I just started playing around with Django and the JavaScript in my static files don't seem to load, while other another resources like  *logo.png* seems to load fine. Am I missing something really basic? Or what I am doing wrong?

**My setup**

- Using Docker with Python 3.5 with and Django 2.1 as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/)
- My static files are in `app\static\app` as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/)
- I have a JavaScript file (`d3.js`) and an image (`logo.png`) in the above directory
- In my template I have `<script type="text/javascript" href="{% static 'app/d3.js' %}"></script>`
- In settings.py I have `DEBUG = True` (default)
- On a Windows environment

**Tried solutions**

- I can find the files with `python manage.py findstatic app/d3.js`
- I tried adding `STATICFILES_DIRS` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627393/docker-django-404-for-web-static-files-but-fine-for-admin-static-files), but that didn't seem to work.

**Directory**

`├───project
│   └───__pycache__
└───app
    ├───migrations
    │   └───__pycache_
    ├───static
    │   └───app
    ├───templates
    │   └───app
    └───__pycache__`

---

**HTML**

```html
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
 
<div id="graphic"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" href="{% static 'app/d3.js' %}"></script>

<script>
        D3 things going on here            
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

**Edit**: Seems to work when I change the HTML into `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/app/d3.js"></script>`

Comment: You might have a completely different issue. Please post your settings and the whole template.

Comment: What do you mean by "do not seem to load" ? Please inspect the response (status and body) you get for those urls (you can check this in your browser's developers tools or just directly type the url in your browser).

Comment: Also Include the App directory in your question.

Comment: Changed the static URL and now seems to be fine. Don't understand the difference though. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work when I change the HTML into: 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/app/d3.js"></script>`