# django inlinecss not loading css file correctly

Tags: html, css, django

I'm using [django-inlinecss](https://github.com/roverdotcom/django-inlinecss) to style emails.

Here's a snippet of my email template:

```html
{% extends "base/email.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% load inlinecss %}
    {% inlinecss "base/css/email.css" %}
        <p class="c-c-test">test</p>
    {% endinlinecss %}
{% endblock %}
```

When rendering the template, an error occurs saying:

*No such file or directory: '/usr/src/project/static/base/css/email.css'*

Although, trying to use the same css file path (i.e. `"base/css/email.css"`) with `static` template tag works fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

I'm using docker, `django-inlinecss` seems to load the css file from local storage (i.e. from docker image) where there's no such file. The actual file is located on my machine. Is there a workaround to solve this issue? something like how `static` template tag work?

Comment: is it `emails.css` or `email.css` ? you have mentioned it differently at two places

Comment: Sorry, it's `email.css` I mentioned it wrong, edited the question.

Comment: And you are 100% sure there is a file named email.css at the following location: '/usr/src/project/static/base/css/email.css' ?

Comment: I edited my question, please have a look now.

Comment: may be this reply could help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38634556/2348704