# Why is CSS not working even I use 'runserver' command in Docker?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to develop a web application using `Django` in `Docker`.

I made a `DockerFile` and a `docker-compose.yml` file as below to check the code in the development environment.

Even though I'm using the `runserver` command in the file, when I start the `container` and access the localhost, the `CSS` for the admin page isn't working.

[image]

How should I change the codes to make it work?

---

Here are the codes:

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: ./django_project
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./django_project/:/usr/src/app/

    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

---

docker desktop: 4.1.1

Python: 3.8

Django: 3.0

Comment: Have you run `./manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: @ SUTerliakov, Yes, I've already tried it, but CSS doesn't work

Comment: Well, it is slightly difficult to debug. At least provide your folder structure. Have a look at [deployment guideline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/) and [don't use `runserver` to deploy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver)

Comment: The `volumes:` block hides everything in your image, so if you do any setup there it will be lost.  You shouldn't need a Compose `command:` override normally either; the Dockerfile `CMD` should be sufficient.  Do you see the browser application trying to fetch the CSS file; can you make the same request with a command-line tool like `curl`?  Is there anything interesting in the container logs?  If you do inspect the container filesystem, is the CSS file there somewhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Django 404 for web static files, but fine for admin static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627393/docker-django-404-for-web-static-files-but-fine-for-admin-static-files)

Comment: Does it work without containerization? Like with `runserver` on a host machine, without docker.

Comment: @Ivan Starostin, Yes when I use `runserver` without docker css works well.

Comment: Please show your folder structure as already asked above and settings.py part related to the static files. Also please grab  generated static file url from rendered page when running in docker container and put this url into browser address bar, open it manually and add specific http status/ error message to your question too.